# Jmeter - Simple HTTP request

Tags: jmeter

I am very new to Jmeter and learning step by step.

Tried to create simple HTTP request in Jmeter and on Protocol tab- i have given "google.com".

while i run this, getting error as mentioned below:

Response code   : Non HTTP response code : java.net.Malformed URL Exception

Response Message : Non HTTP response message: unknown protocol:google.com

Please help me to overcome this error and pass the test successfully.

Best Regards,
Govindarajan G

Answer (score 0):

You can enter full URL as `http://www.google.com` to [HTTP Request](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request)'s Path field:

> As a special case, if the path starts with "http://" or "https://" then this is used as the full URL.

Or enter domain name  `www.google.com`  in Server Name field:

> Server
>   Domain name or IP address of the web server, e.g. www.example.com. [Do not include the http:// prefix.]

Protocol is used mainly to indicate if using HTTPS or HTTP

> Protocol
>   HTTP, HTTPS or FILE. Default: HTTP

Notice if you want to reuse domain for several requests you can use  [HTTP Request Defaults](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#HTTP_Request_Defaults)

> add a single HTTP Request Defaults element with the "Server Name or IP" field filled in. Then, when you add the 25 HTTP Request controllers, leave the "Server Name or IP" field empty. The controllers will inherit this field value from the HTTP Request Defaults element.

Answer (score 0):

You need to put your application under test host into "Server Name or IP" field of the HTTP Request sampler:

[image: JMeter HTTP Request Domain]

Request and response can be visualized using [View Results Tree](http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#View_Results_Tree) listener.

---

Also be aware that you can quickly get started with JMeter by recording your test actions performed in browser.

1. Configure JMeter for recording. The easiest way is using J[Meter Templates Feature](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-save-%E2%80%98loads%E2%80%99-time-using-jmeters-template-feature)

   - From JMeter main menu choose `File -> Templates -> Recording` and click "Create"
   - Open HTTP(S) Test Script Recorder and click "Start"
2. Prepare browser for recording. Configure it to use `localhost:8888` as [the proxy server](https://library.medicine.yale.edu/services/computing/configure-browser)
3. Open your application under test in browser and perform an action - JMeter will record the requests under `Thread Group -> Recording Controller`

More information: [Apache JMeter proxy Step-by-step](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf)